# how can i compare an element stored in an Arraylist with an integer?

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to check elements in the ArrayList with integers given by users to see if that integer is already there in the list or not.

Comment: Ckeck the ArrayList javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Post your code and show what you've tried. If you got no code: Try it first and come back if you're not able to do it.

Comment: Also, consider using `Set`, for example `HashSet`.

Comment: Also there is a [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [ArrayList.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// populate your list here
Integer i = 1;
System.out.println(list.contains(i));
```

You have to autobox primitive `int` type into `Integer` since `ArrayList<T>` uses generics and they [don't allow to use primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate).

**EDITED** for purists.

Comment: But of course, if you only want to know if the elements are already there, a Set would probably be better than a list.

Comment: @NeerajJain of course, you won't run this code as is. `list` and `int` are supposed to exist before running `list.contains`.

Comment: Boom, NPE :P better to refer the OP to docs instead of trying to answer the question with this kind of incomplete code

Comment: once again, it's a pseudocode.. not to be compiled as such

Comment: Just for record, don't forget about the overriding the equals() method while using contains(). Though it's not required since you are using Integer